# C# Search for all possible options

Tags: c#, combinatorics

There is the following option for writing a line:

```
"1X2;12;X;2;X;X;1;X;1;1;X;X;1;2;1"
```

from it you need to get all the variations:

```
"1;1;X;2;X;X;1;X;1;1;X;X;1;2;1"  
"1;2;X;2;X;X;1;X;1;1;X;X;1;2;1"    
"X;1;X;2;X;X;1;X;1;1;X;X;1;2;1"  
"X;2;X;2;X;X;1;X;1;1;X;X;1;2;1"
"2;1;X;2;X;X;1;X;1;1;X;X;1;2;1"  
"2;2;X;2;X;X;1;X;1;1;X;X;1;2;1"
```

I understand the algorithm itself, but something does not work with the implementation.
I would be very grateful if someone could tell you how you can make a universal method that will produce all possible options.

Comment: Would be so great if you can add description of how the second part is generated from the first, because... _we_ don't understand the algorithm.

Comment: What is your implementation?

Comment: Roughly speaking, it is divided into 15 columns, each contains a combination of 3 symbols '1X2'. At the output, we should get a list of strings without concatenated characters. In general, it turns out if there are 3 characters in each column, we get 3^15 options.

Comment: I tried to do it using FOR and at each iteration check the size of the current element, if it is greater than 1, then create a new line and then check it. But it didn't work out very well for me)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of your attempt and explain what's not working in that code.

Comment: I have added some sample code. I go through each element and if I stumble upon an element with Lenght> 1, I need to make a new array with the elements already passed before and then add new ones, which should also not be greater than 1

Comment: "each contains a combination of 3 symbols '1X2'" - I don't see your sample input matches this description. Plus: please [edit] your question to add more information, it is easily overlooked in the comments.

Comment: `1X2;1;X;2` will produce three lines `1;1;X;2`, `X;1;X;2` and `2;1;X;2`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I have already posted the answer with the solution below)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved a solution to my problem. Maybe someone will come in handy.

```
public static List<string> ParseString(string s, string separator)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string[] words = s.Split(new string[] { separator },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int len = words.Length;
    if (len == 0) return result;

    int[] positions = new int[len];
    char[] symbols = new char[len];

    int changePosition = 0;
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) symbols[i] = words[i][positions[i]];
        result.Add(string.Join(separator, symbols));

        while (changePosition < len)
        {
            if (positions[changePosition] < words[changePosition].Length-1)
            {
                positions[changePosition]++;
                changePosition = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                positions[changePosition] = 0;
                changePosition++;
            }
        }
    } while (changePosition < len);
    return result;
}
```